# 85 Upvotes and Deleted

Tags: discussion, moderation

I see that the question on the Charleston shooting has been deleted, with the only notification being the adding of the "completed" tag to the [question discussing it](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/why-is-the-mass-shooting-question-locked-closed).

I'm obviously aware of the discussion around this question, but given the content of the discussion I'm surprised to see it deleted. Let me reiterate some of the facts:

- The question had 85 upvotes
- The top answer had 129 upvotes
- On the meta-question discussing it, most of the answers - including the most upvoted answer - indicated that the question was salvageable
- The only real objection to the question appears to have been that it was unclear. There were several volunteers to fix up the question, but no indication from the moderators as to what would constitute an acceptable fix.
- Reluctant as I am, it has to be said that the impression in the discussion was that the community was in favour of leaving it open, while the moderators favoured closing it.

Let me re-iterate my opinion that this question should remain on the site, and my belief that the community agrees with this. Let me also re-iterate my offer to make the question clearer.

To be specific, here is my first proposal for a rewrite of the question. I would be obliged if moderators would indicate what would prevent this question from being asked.

## Proposed Question

In response to the shooting in Charleston, South Carolina, President Obama asserted that:

> But let’s be clear: at some point, we as a country will have to reckon
>   with the fact that this type of mass violence does not happen in other
>   advanced countries. It doesn’t happen in other places with this kind
>   of frequency.

President Obama's statements have been interpreted in a number of ways:

1. This type of mass violence does not, in general, happen in other advanced countries with as high a frequency as the US.
2. There are no other advanced countries in which this kind of mass violence happens with as high a frequency as the US

(We will ignore the trivially false interpretation that "This kind of mass violence does not happen at all outside the US")

([cites for above](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/jun/22/barack-obama/barack-obama-correct-mass-killings-dont-happen-oth/))

I am interested in answers to either or both of these interpretations.

By "this kind of mass violence" I understand him to mean shootings of strangers with multiple fatalities. I will take any reasonable definition of "multiple" for which statistics can be found.

I will take any reasonable definition of 'advanced countries".

Comment: Do you have citations not only for the quote, but also the interpretations (1) and (2)? Such citations might be found in news/magazine articles examining the statement or in responses by political opponents or pundits.

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Let's not have the same discussion twice. I think we'd all be happy to undelete this if it's suitable for the site. At the moment the question is flamebait and the top voted answer is OR, which is why it is hidden.

Comment: Nothing says meta like discussing the discussion about a discussion. In any case, I have not been too involved in this, I just wanted to comment that it's a shame we cant find a way to get such a wide-ranging interesting question fixed up - for no other reason than the additional traffic it brings us.

Comment: @Sklivvz So at the root of this question - if the original question was edited like I propose, can it be undeleted and opened?

Comment: Honestly, not from me, I think you are forcing a specific interpretation on a generic claim, creating an involuntary straw man. Also, two answers are original research and should not be undeleted until fixed.

Comment: Otoh: there are many more mods here that can undelete the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth: For what little it is worth, your concern hasn't been ignored. There has been yet another mod discussion about how the question can be rescued. So far, we can't see a way. Every solution is bad.

Comment: 'unclear questions' are the stock in trade of this site. Let's take [this question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/do-cacti-absorb-harmful-radiation-emitted-by-computers) for example. The question doesn't specify what kind of radiation is being talked about, or what part of the computer is suppoed to be emitting raditation. Yet the question got 21 upvotes, and the answer got 40 upvotes by taking a reasonable explanation and analysing it. Neither question nor answer received any criticism, and was certainly not deleted.

Comment: @djc in that example there is vagueness but not different interpretations, original research answers and hundreds of deleted comments. If *that* doesn't convince you the question has huge problems, nothing will.

Comment: By the way: the question owner had been notified of the deletion with a comment. The status completed tag had already been added to remove the question from the community bulletin and has nothing to do with it. The deletion happened after weeks of no action being taken on the closed question, no edits, reopen votes...

Comment: 1) Just because a question has a poor answer doesn't make it a bad question. (I want to come to the question of "original research" later, but let's not muddy the waters) 2) Hundreds of deleted comments just means the question is controversial. Just because a question is controversial doesn't make it a bad question 3) I'm not sure what the difference between 'vagueness' and 'interpretations' is. To my mind, if a question is vague, that *means* it is open to different interpretations. It it wasn't open to different interpretations, it wouldn't be vague. ...

Comment: ... The question as it stands certainly has problems, but plenty of people have said they were fixable. What would constititute a good question on this subject? It's hard to believe that it's inherently impossble.

Comment: @DJClayworth the proof is in the pudding: a fixed question certainly proves that it's fixable. A closed question without any edit or reopen vote for weeks makes me suspect that it's either not fixable or that no one is willing to fix it. That said: the quality of answers and comments is certainly a reason to reject a question. In fact, avoiding such questions is why we have a "primarily opinion based" close reason...

Comment: Which brings me again to my question: is the question I proposed acceptable? If not what makes it unacceptable, and would make it acceptable?

Comment: I believe I've repeatedly tried to tell you, and you expressed disagreement. For example find a different notable source that claims the same thing, without the double meaning.

Comment: @DJClayworth I too have noticed censorship. http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/why-do-mods-censor-questions-on-this-site